# Nginx Reverse Proxy + ExpressJS + Angular + SSL configuration issues

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ssl, nginx

I'm new to this stuff and I have a few questions I couldn't answer through Google.

If I get it right - **nginx** is my webserver - a request to my server is done and **nginx** serves my client (Angular) but can I also use my Express app to serve it with `res.sendFile()`?
And if I setup nginx with a reverse proxy it works as an instance between my client and backend? So they don't communicate directly with eachother but through nginx and to do so I have to `proxy_pass` my Express app?

My nginx sites-available config:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name blank-agency.org www.blank-agency.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
} 


server {    
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl on;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/blank-agency.org/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/blank-agency.org/privkey.pem;

server_name blank-agency.org www.blank-agency.org;  
root /var/www/webserver/public/website;



    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }


location / {

    proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}
```

As you can see my directory structure is:

/var/www/webserver --> here is my express app.js

/var/www/webserver/public/website --> here are my angular dist files

If I use nginx as a reverse proxy my client is not served anymore (`bad gateway 502`) so I suppose I have to serve it via my Express app now?

So now my `app.js`:

```
// require section

var express = require('express'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    path = require('path'),
    app = express();

// middlewares bodyParser + cors
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());



var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'whatever',
    database: 'whateverDB'
});

connection.connect();


app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/public/website'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/website/index.html'));
});

app.route('/customers').get((req, res) => {
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM customers', function (err, rows) {
      const results = JSON.stringify(rows);
      console.log(req.param("term"));
      res.send(results);
   })

})



// app listen port

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Again everything seem to work fine...but why can I access my app through `http://blank-agency.org:3000`? First of all HTTP requests should be redirected to HTTPS? Same for https://blank-agency/customers --> my data exposed on an URL seems like an security issue haha

I get that it is served on port `3000` cause I sent it through my Express app which listens on port 3000 but how else should it be served? Because nginx with reverse proxy setting gives `502` error like mentioned and i already opened the ports `80 & 443` on my Firewall through `iptables` on linux.

```
netstat -tlpn
```

show nginx on ports 80 and 443

```
systemctl status nginx
```

and

```
nginx -t
```

says all fine.

I suppose I have a deep misunderstanding of the concepts used here or something else isn't right.
Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you don't want to reach `expressjs` server on port 3000, just specify the `host/bind` address in `listen` method like `localhost`. Then `expressjs` will be accessible only via `http://localhost:3000` which shall be reachable by sibling `nginx` process, but not from public interface like `http://blank-agency.org:3000`.

Comment: For the other part, don't serve folders form `nginx`, just reverse proxy to `http://localhost:3000`, then everything else can be handled by `expressjs`. Otherwise, if you want to serve static files from `nginx`, then make sure that you reverse proxy only your API locations, so it should be `location /customers { proxy_pass https://localhost:3000/customers; ...` in your nginx config. Then what ever will come to `/` will be handled by `nginx root /var/www/webserver/public/website;` and `/customers` will be handed over via reverse proxy to `expressjs`

Comment: @muradm hey, thank you for your fast response. i get what you are saying but isn't it a security issue to see my data via an URL or do i have to make an auth service to make it "secure"? like JWT standard?

Comment: Of course, if you require authentication, your `angular` application and `node/expressjs` should implement that, then you will have more paths for reverse proxy, like `location /api/auth { ... }` etc. But that part is application specific, `nginx` will just handover HTTP requests to `node/expressjs`, and responses to client. From `nginx` perspective it should be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part:

```
app.listen(3000, 'localhost', function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

This will prevent access to `http://blank-agency.org:3000`, because now `node` with `expressjs` won't listen on all addresses, but only `localhost`. (assuming that both nginx and node/expressjs run on same server).

For the second part:

```
location /customers {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:3000/customers;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

This will reverse proxy only `https://blank-agency.org/customers` to `node/expressjs`. In order to reduce configuration burden, better to collect all `expressjs` URLs under common path like: `/api/customers`, `/api/products`, `/api/auth` etc. This way, you will have to reverse proxy configure only once from `/api`.

if you require authentication, your `angular` application and `node/expressjs` should implement that, then you will have more paths for reverse proxy, like `location /api/auth { ... }` etc. But that part is application specific, `nginx` will just handover HTTP requests to `node/expressjs`, and responses to client. From `nginx` perspective it should be transparent.

Comment: thank you.... 8h to get this working or to prevent it from working haha.... and it was just adding 'localhost' to app.listen - sometimes frustrating :D

Comment: That is simple solution. Normally, you would run public application some where behind a type of firewall or a like, and only enable ports which should be accessible, rather than closing what is open selectively. Because if you go this way, you have to bear in mind every application that may listen on public ports on that server. But it is also a way.

Comment: well i use this solution for now to get movin' - when i'm used to core elements i come back and do it in a more common way
thank you again and have a nice time :)
cya again

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can absolutely serve files through both Nginx and express-static.

I have this in my server.js, which serves all files within `./public/` when run locally without Nginx.

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
```

Then in Nginx configuration I have this to serve the same directory. In a production environment, it will be fully handled by Nginx and never hit the Express app for `/assets`.

```
location /assets/ {
    alias /home/app/public/;
    sendfile on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 5m;
    tcp_nopush on;
  }
```

My proxy-pass is a little more complicated due to Prerender.io configuration but you'll want something along these lines. This will send anything *except* `/assets/` to your Express server.

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```