# Install and configure a nodejs application on a ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am a little lost in this moment. It is my first time with **nodejs** (I have more experience with **Php/Apache**). Recently a client gave me access to a **bitbucket repository** where he had the code of one application on **nodejs**. My final goal is to install that application on a Linux dev server.

Reading a little on the internet, I launch a **Ubuntu 16.04** Instance on **AWS**. I installed **Node.js** and **npm** like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

And if I run these commands, it returns my the versions:

```
node --version
v4.4.5
npm --version
2.15.5
```

So, my question is... now what? I have been searching on the internet by a couple hours, and all the tutorials about install node on ubuntu stop right here, but I didn´t find how to configure an app right from the start, and how to install the bitbucket project on my server, and how I made this site accessible by my browser.

On a **Php/Apache** server I must create the project directory con **/var/www/**, made a **git clone** on that directory and configure the site's **virtualhost**, and access by **http://ip_address/**, How I do that in this case?

I'm sorry, I know maybe these are very basic questions, but really, as I said, I feel lost.

Comment: can u post the `package.json` file ?

Comment: Using [Docker](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-application-to-amazon-web-services-using-docker-81c2a2d7225b) is one option: : https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-nodejs-web-app/

Answer (score 1):

If you use express.js for the Webapplication, you first could use `pm2` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) to create a "container" for your application. If you want to Host your application, I recommend using Nginx with a reverse proxy.
Here are some Links:

1. https://serverfault.com/questions/601332/how-to-configure-nginx-so-it-works-with-express
2. [Nginx Reverse Proxy + ExpressJS + Angular + SSL configuration issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807393/nginx-reverse-proxy-expressjs-angular-ssl-configuration-issues)

I hope that helps you. And if you want to install your application, just run `npm install` in the directory where the `package.json` is. Maybe you should update node.js because version 4.x is absolutely outdated.

Comment: There are many options.  An "enterprise" would probably be using Docker/Kubernetes.  A "developer" would probably just type "node index.js" from an ssh session.  I absolutely agree with you that PM2 in conjunction with Nginx is probably an ideal "middle ground".  Here's another tutorial (where the NodeJS project happens to hosted on BitBucket, with the NodeJS app hosted on AWS with Nginx): https://hackernoon.com/deploy-your-node-js-app-in-production-and-use-bitbucket-to-automate-your-deployment-50b07b18914c

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to manually deploy the app to EC2 and run it yourself, here's what's left to do:

1. Change your current directory to where you'd like to store the app (I usually use `/home/ec2-user`, but it doesn't really matter).
2. Clone the Git repo and `cd` into it.
3. Install the app's dependencies by running `npm install`. *Note that the app might have additional dependencies you'll have to install manually.*
4. This step depends on the application itself, but usually you can run a Node.js app by either running `npm start` (if the `start` script has been configured in `package.json`), or by running `node index.js` (you can replace `index.js` with any other file, in case the main file isn't named `index.js`).
5. Now you need to expose the ports the application listens to by modifying the instance's VPC settings. More info on how to do this can be found in [the official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html).
6. Now you should be able to access your app by going to `http://public_ip:port`, where `public_ip` is the public IP address of your EC2 instance (which can be found in the management console (see more on this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#using-instance-addressing-common)), and `port` is the port the app is running on.